# How to hide a file path in the menu bar of IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2?

Tags: user-interface, intellij-idea

Version 2019.2 of IntelliJ IDEA for some unknown reason has started to show full file path of the current file in the menu bar, after 'Help' item.

How to hide this path?? How to make menu bar to appear clean and normal as it used to be in version 2019.1 and before?

Answer (score 1):

View>Appearance>Navigation Bar

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the Navigation Bar:

*View > Appearance > Navigation Bar*

This may have the side effect of also removing the Main Toolbar. Add it back again with:

*View > Appearance > Toolbar*

Note however that this will cause the toolbar to appear on the left-hand side from now on instead of on the right.